# ADO task "DownloadPipelineArtifact@2" doesn't copy with folders

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I download ADO build artifacts using "DownloadPipelineArtifact@2" this causes that It downloads as files one with folder another without folder. But, When I try to run with "DownloadBuildArtifact@1" it works as it downloads all files and folder to target location as same as artifact structure. Why there is this much different between two tasks? Previously, I was confused with [databricks here but root cause with the task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76426447/databricks-cli-copy-command-not-copying-folder-but-copied-only-files)

Imagine my artifact named 'animal' contains two subfolders like below and after download 'animal' folder in destination is not as same as artifact structure.

animal folder in artifact contains below subfolders and files in it:

- animal\land\gorilla.txt
- animal\land\tiger.txt
- animal\land\lion.txt
- animal\sea\fish.txt
- animal\sea\shark.txt
- animal\sea\whale.txt

After download above artifact to my target destination is looks below:

- C:myname\drop\animal\land\gorilla.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\land\tiger.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\land\lion.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\fish.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\shark.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\whale.txt

I expect something below in target location,

- C:myname\drop\animal\land\gorilla.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\land\tiger.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\land\lion.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\sea\fish.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\sea\shark.txt
- C:myname\drop\animal\sea\whale.txt

Could you tell me why 'sea' folder is missing but it does copied all files?

Below is YAML task for download artifact ( both YAML and classic this issue persists ):

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    buildType: specific
    project: '0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000'
    definition: 12345
    artifactName: animal
    targetPath: drop
```

I copy them in my ADO agent's working directory (System.workingDirectory) with name of folder 'drop' as mentioned in task.

Folder structure in artifacts looks something below:

```
> animal_rootFolder
 - UnderRootFolderFile1.ini
 > subFolder_land_Template
 - UnderRootFolderFile2.ini
 - UnderRootFolderFile3.ini
 - UnderRootFolderFile4.ini
 - UnderRootFolderFile5.ini
 > subFolder_Sea_configFiles
```

I have subfolder structure for other artifacts too but they working fine. Only above structure didn't work, Particularly sea folder at last as specified.

Below is publish artifact YAML task - this will publish 'config' folder from my ADO Repo and put them in same name in artifact.

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Build Artifact - config
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: animal_rootFolder
      ArtifactName: animal_rootFolder
```

Again to remind, 'DownloadBuildArtifacts@1' works fine but 'DownloadPipelineArtifact@2' is the issue all above.

Comment: Show where you're publishing the artifacts. What do the artifacts look like in the UI?

Comment: Thanks for looking into, Daniel. I've added structrue above with target location.

Comment: Please add yaml snippet for the step that publishes the artefact.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I've added the snippet.

Comment: Try to avoid mixing the `Pipeline` and `Build` artifact tasks. i.e. if you use `PublishPipelineArtifact`, use `DownloadPipelineArtifact`. If you use `PublishBuildArtifact`, use `DownloadBuildArtifact`. They *should* be cross-compatible, but being consistent is a good idea. Note you can use the `publish` and `download` aliases for the `*PipelineArtifact` set of steps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll keep note of it.